# AQ Hobsbawm ability clarification

Tags: arcadia-quest

Did his ability get updated? The hero card that I have in my core set states that the player can only activate another hero within line of sight but the hero card online at the arcadia quest website doesn't have the line of sight restriction. I'm assuming the hero card online is the correct version but I just want to make sure.

Crossposted on [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1286449/aq-hobsbawms-ability-clarification).

Comment: Given my experience with Magic and Oracle text, I would guess the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line of sight is required [according](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/17761986#17761986) to the game's designer.

> The card in your core set is the most up-to-date.